# Navigating to Composable Screen from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, broadcastreceiver, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm working on an Android app using Jetpack Compose and I need to implement Alarm Clock functionality. This in itself is working but I'm trying to figure out how to launch a Composable Screen (i.e., the Alarm UI) after receiving the alarm.

I am using Hilt and Compose Navigation, setup up like in the [*Make it so* sample app](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/make-it-so-android/blob/main/final/app/src/main/java/com/example/makeitso/MakeItSoApp.kt)
There is an AppState class which has a NavHostController and is making the *navigate* calls. The NavGraph is build through an extension to the NavGraphBuilder (makeItSoGraph() in the example) which takes a reference to the appState. All of the Composable screens called there can hoist their navigation functions up to this point where they are completed using the appState.

The question is now: How do I navigate to a new Composable screen from the BroadcastReceiver class, especially considering that the alarm might occur while the device is sleeping and the app isn't active?
I can't hoist a function call to the NavGraph because the BroadcastReceiver wasn't created by the NavGraph. Can I get a hold of the navigation controller somehow and would it be architecturally smart to do so?

Comment: it will be helpful if you show your code. but i think it will be possible with `startDestination`
just dont give this argument as a static string!

Comment: I thought about adding code but since the implementation is identical to the Make It So app and the question is more of an architectural one I wasn't sure which parts were relevant. I am using startDestination on startup, while building the NavHost in the main scaffold but I don't reach that from the BroadcastReceiver's OnReceive @MohammadBaqer

Comment: With two activities you can have two entry points, inside of 'OnReceive' start another activity with another NavHost. But this is not a clean way